# How to reduce Physical Memory usage in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 32 GB physical memory server. When I am starting my server its taking 18gb memory when the server and SQL Server 2008 R2 will up. But after few hours SQL Server will be taking up 23gb or more cached size going 4939 or more. What is the cause of this problem and how can I see which queries making this problem?`

Comment: I am not sure if that's a problem. I think SQL Server uses a lot of memory to cache tables and speed up its performance. So basically it's using what it has to work faster. What's the overall size of all its databases?

Comment: MS SQL Server uses **ALL** available memory to cache data. If you really need some memory for other processes then you can change **Maximum server memory (in MB)**. Default value **2147483647** (in MB) is just a phone number.

Comment: *What is the cause of this problem* - **nothing**, because it's ***NOT*** a problem, it's the way SQL Server is designed to work, to take up as much memory as it can get to make its operations as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 0):

SQL loves memory, it'll use what it needs to, especially when caching data. The very nature of caching data is using memory. If your concerned about leaving a little memory for the server or other processes running on your server, then set a max memory amount to SQL.